# Checking and Remedying Null Objects Efficiently

Tags: objective-c, instantiation, null, performance

Has anyone found a more efficient way of checking if a variable is nil, then instantiating it?  I know the classic way is to write:

```
if (myObject == nil) {
    //instantiate and do other stuff
}
```

Or

```
if (!myobect) { 
    //do stuff
}
```

Which seems too boiler-plate-esque for my liking, especially if I have to do it many times.

EDIT: Having had a stroke of inspiration, would something like this work?

```
-(id)instantiateIfObjectIsNull:(id)object withClass:(Class*)class {
    if (object == nil) {
        object = [[Class alloc]init];
    }
    return object;
}
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to check if something is `nil` and if so to instantiate it than to check if it's `nil` and if so, instantiate it? Not really... This is the most efficient way to do it. You can write your if-statement differently, but essentially, you're not going to be changing much around. Checking if something is `nil` is the same as negating it (`(myObject == nil) == (!myObject`), but otherwise, there's nothing much left to do.

Comment: Really?  Even just a simple instance method that I could delegate this to?

Comment: Nope. There's no reason to; it would even generate overhead.

Comment: Disappointing... But check the edit.  Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: That works (although it would be better as a function, since there's no reason to associate it with a class), but if you're talking about "efficiency", it's a loss, since you incur the overhead of a method call. It doesn't even really seem to save much typing. `if( !pointer ){ pointer = [[Class alloc] initWithThingy:thingy]; }` compared to `pointer = createIfNull(pointer, [SomeClass class]);`? I guess it saves a bit, but don't forget code is "Write once, read many".

Comment: Perhaps 'efficient' isn't quite the word I'm looking for.  Just something to cut down on the number of times I have to write that cursed if-else statement.

Comment: Also, what are you going to do if you need to pass arguments to the initializer?

Comment: Hmm... Methinks the need for a special class dedicated to this might be in order.

Comment: I think it would be best to leave this alone, really. You might save yourself a line of code here and there (I mean, these if-statements are already potentially one-liners anyway), but it's not worth it in terms of code readability, maintainability, and flexibility. I doubt the overhead is worth saving writing a few short lines of code. This is, of course, not to mention the fact that writing `if (!object) object = [[AClass alloc] init]` is _shorter_ than writing `object = [SomeClass instantiateIfObjectIsNull:object withClass:AClass]`, and undoubtedly more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

well it is essentially the same thing but

```
   if (!myobject) {
     .....
   }
```

Comment: I was looking for more of a one-off kind of method that could be placed in a class like `[self InstantiateifIsNull:object];`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ObjC++, you could approach it from this angle:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

template < typename T >
void InitIfNil(T*& obj) {
    if (nil == obj)
        obj = [T new];
}

template < typename T >
void TryIt() {
    T * obj(nil);
    NSLog(@"before: %@", obj);
    InitIfNil(obj);
    NSLog(@"after: %s : %@", object_getClassName(obj), obj);
    [obj release];
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        TryIt<NSArray>();
        TryIt<NSString>();
        TryIt<NSMutableSet>();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This could also be done with a macro... I don't think this helps readability though.

A third option would be C11 generics - when your compiler supports them.

Comment: Yeah, and the problem with this is that again, it doesn't offer any flexibility with initialization - you don't always wan't `new`.

Comment: @ItaiFerber all options do, provided no parameters are required. C++: template specialization. C macro: init by parameter `InitIfNil(obj, [[NSArray alloc] init])`. C11 generic: overloadable.

Comment: Not knocking your code, just pointing out the inherent problems with this type of approach. ;)

Comment: @ItaiFerber no worries. i'm aware of the problems. i'm just trying to answer the question, regardless of whether i would actually use this solution myself in my programs.